# command line displaying encoded text

Tags: oracle, command-line, fonts, character-encoding

I have a Windows 7 64-bit, Home Premium which I bought in Russia. I installed Oracle 11g on it but every time I run some command using the command prompt, the command prompt is displaying encoded or encrypted like text that I cannot read...like the text below:

```
C:\Users\elgin>sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on ┬ё ─хъ 29 08:27:38 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

╤юхфшэхэ ё яЁюёЄрштр■∙шь ¤ъчхьяы Ёюь.

SQL> startup
▌ъчхьяы Ё ORACLE чряє∙хэ.

Total System Global Area 1603411968 bytes
Fixed Size                  2176168 bytes
Variable Size            1040190296 bytes
Database Buffers          553648128 bytes
Redo Buffers                7397376 bytes
┴рчр фрээ√ї ёьюэЄшЁютрэр.
┴рчр фрээ√ї юЄъЁ√Єр.
SQL> exit
╬Єёюхфшэхэю юЄ Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit
 Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

How can I make my command prompt stop displaying encoded characters?

Answer (score 3):

you need to set the below parameter.(enviromental variable)

```
set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1;
```

other way by registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\NLS_LANG
```

Comment: See also the [Oracle FAQ about NLS_LANG](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/globalization/nls-lang-099431.html) to understand what this is doing and how to choose the right value.